# Filter data using a multiselect. When selecting 2 or 3 options result need to throw only registers where options together exist

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

thank you in advance for reading me. So I have been working in a filte. Right now my filter works, however doesn't do what I want. The current status is. When I select 2 options or more. I get all the values inside the data that contains either optionA oder optionB.

[image]

See my example data below:

```
{
  "_uid": "1",
  "body": [
    {
      "_uid": "2",
      "name": "John",
      "image": {
        "id": 6807178,
        "filename": "https://",
        "copyright": "",
        "fieldtype": "asset",
        "is_external_url": false
      },
      "gewerk": "Project Owner",
      "skill": ["vuejs", "react", "symfony"],
      "component": "person",
    },
    {
      "_uid": "3",
      "name": "Jean",
      "image": {
        "id": 6807182,
        "filename": "https://",
        "copyright": "",
        "fieldtype": "asset",
        "is_external_url": false
      },
      "gewerk": "UI",
      "skill": ["svelte"],
      "component": "person",
    },
    {
      "_uid": "4",
      "name": "Martha",
      "gewerk": "Frontend",
      "skill": ["vuejs", "react"],
      "component": "person",
    },
    {
      "_uid": "5",
      "name": "Tom",
      "gewerk": "UI",
      "skill": ["svelte", "angular", "vuejs"],
      "component": "person",
    }
  ],
}
```

With that being says when I filter using this example combi(screenshot). I get Martha, Tom and John as a result. When what I actually want is to have only Tom as a result. because only Tom have both criterias together inside his skills data.

This is my current computed function:

```
    filterPersonSkill() {
      return this.getComponentPerson.filter((e) =>
        e.skill.map((skill) => this.multiValue.includes(skill)).includes(true)
      );
    }
```

At the beginning I used includes instead of map and that worked half. Because I was getting the result only if I selected in the same order(in the multiselect) as the array skills was appearing. Example below

```
    filterPersonSkill() {
      return this.getComponentPerson.filter((e) =>
        e.skill.includes(...this.multiValue)
      );
    }
```

Thank in advance for the advice and reading me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it will be much simpler, if you add checkbox for the user to use "exact" filtering, i.e. results which include only selected tags.
With such a checkbox you can do something like this:

```
// your vue component
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      exactMatch: true,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterPersonSkillExactMatch() {
       const result = [];
       for (const p of this.getComponentPerson) {
         if (p.skill.length === this.multiValue.length
             && this.multiValue.every(val => p.skill.includes(val))) {
             result.push(p)
         }
       }
       return result
     }
// somewhere in your code (either computed prop or method):
     filteredPersons() {
        if (exactMatch) {
          return this.filterPersonSkillExactMatch()
        }
        return this.filterPerson()
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Anton, thank you very much to take the time to write. I tried your solution and the idea is interesting, however I am only getting always only one result. I am assuming is the first position of the result. I could imagine is something related with the push of the result?

Comment: Okay, please forget my last question, I solved it myself, but with your help, so will mark yours as answer, what I did only was to remove the (p.skill.length === this.multiValue.length) from the if, now it works, so thank you veeery much : ). Now I am reading about "every" function that is something that I never used before